# How can I move a dot 6 spaces to the left on all values of a column in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

The title resumes it all.

I have a column named "weight" and some values like "`2000000.0000`", for example.

I need the output to be something like "`2.0000000000`", and if the number is something like "`200000.0000`" the output needs to be like "`0.2000000000`".

That's even possible? I don't know, maybe regex?

Comment: Why? Did you store numeric data as character values? Convert back to numeric, and divide.

Comment: `UPDATE table SET col = col / 1000000` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just divide it

```
SELECT weight/1000000 as Weight
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: @shA.t  there is no need, mysql will do that automatically http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/7432

Answer (score 0):

```
Update TableName set col = col/1000000 [where condition]
```